# Add a different value (by groups) to another value in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have two dataframes, I want to subtract the value of column in one dataframe to another, if dataframes are equal in value of another column.

I have two dataframes A and B that are similar to the following:

```
[A]
Col1   Col2
 1      cat
 2      dog
 3      bird
 4      cat
 5      dog

[B]
 Col1    Col2
[cat]   1
[dog]   2
[bird]  3
```

I want to be able to add the values `A$Col1 + B$Col2` if `A$Col2` matches the tag of `[B]` and create a list with the results that will have the same length as the rows in `[A]`

I have tried this code

```
(A$Col1-B$Col2)[A$Col2==B$Col1]
```

which seems to work, but a following warning shows up:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Joy in Data Stuff: to improve your question, please provide the *desired output*. In your case, that would be a dataframe that shows what you want your output to be (typically you hand-code this). [Here is a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It will increase the chance that someone answers your question in a great way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Left_Join` and then create a new column for difference.

```
merge(A, B, by.x = "Col2", by.y = "Col1", all.x = TRUE) %>% mutate(Difference = Col1 - Col2.y )

 Col2 Col1 Col2.y Difference
1 bird    3      3          0
2  cat    1      1          0
3  cat    4      1          3
4  dog    2      2          0
5  dog    5      2          3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse`-style example to join the two dataframes and substract the columns. You can then take the new column and convert it to a list or whatever you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

A <- tibble(
  Col1 = 1:5, 
  Col2 = c("cat", "dog", "bird", "cat", "dog")
)
B <- tibble(
  Col1 = c("cat", "dog", "bird"),
  Col2 = 1:3
)

A %>% 
  left_join(B, by = c("Col2" = "Col1")) %>% 
  mutate(Col3 = Col1 - Col2.y)
```